# Rebuilding QuickFIX/J with Ant

Tags: java, ant, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

The [User FAQ of QuickFIX/J](http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/User+FAQ) describes the opportunity to rebuild the data dictionary of QuickFIX/J to customize the application.

It is described in the FAQs tis way:

> You'll need ant installed.
>
> QF/J generates the source from the DDs in core/src/main/resources. Make a back up of the one you're going to alter, and then alter it however you need to.
>
> Then rebuild as follows:
>
> 1. ant jar
> 2. You will be prompted for a release number; this just determines the suffix given to the jar names. Enter whatever you want.
> 3. Wait for build to finish
> 4. Find your brand-new QF/J jars in core/target/

Unfortunately I could not find the `build.xml` that I have to invoke with `ant`.

Maybe you have experience with this issue and can help me.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

I've found a further guide to rebuild QuickFIX/J [from the official QuickFIX page](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.3/installation.html):

> Building QuickFIX/J
>
> These instructions are for developers who don't want to use the prebuilt binaries or are intending to modify and rebuild the QuickFIX/J code. If you are building the code from the command line you'll need to download and install Ant (version 1.6.3 or newer). If you are building from Eclipse, Ant is included. Building from source requires Java 5+. There are no Java 1.4 sources.
>
> 1. Check out the code from Subversion. See the Subversion guide at Source Forge for more details on access. You will usually want to checkout the trunk directory from the Subversion repository.
> 2. Change directory to the top-level directory of the checked out code. You should see a build.xml file.
> 3. Run ant jar to build the QuickFIX/J and examples jar files. This will also generate all the FIX message-related code for the various FIX versions.
> 4. There is an option for the code generator to use BigDecimal instead of double for fields like price and quantity. To enable this feature pass a -Dgenerator.decimal option on the command line when running the generate.code Ant target.

I've downloaded [the zip from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickfixj/files/?source=navbar), but the whole diretory (and its subdirectories) doesn't contain a `build.xml`?!?!

[image]

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Looks like for 1.6.0 they switched to maven for building. Check /doc/usermanual/installation.html. Probably some online references still refer to 1.5.x.

Comment: I've also updated the [SO answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967804/quickfix-j-mixing-two-different-versions/29971247#29971247) to include building for QF/J 1.6.x