# Reset sequence numbers but don't set ResetSeqNumFlag on Logon

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Our customer (acceptors for this connection) has specified that sequence numbers should be reset after each disconnect or logout, but also that the Logon message may NOT contain the `ResetSeqNumFlag` field.

I've removed the field from the Logon message in `FIX44.xml` but it's still being populated. From what I understand, as long as `ResetOnLogon`, `ResetOnLogout` or `ResetOnDisconnect` is set, the field will be populated.

How can I prevent `ResetSeqNumFlag` from being set regardless of other settings?

FIX version: 4.4

quickfixj version: 1.5.3

Comment: You will need to modify the library code to do this. Surprisingly your customer seems to be a bit weird who cannot take care of a non required field in an incoming message.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. And yeah, they are very specific about things.

Comment: *"I've removed the field from the Logon message in FIX44.xml but it's still being populated"* > You could try rebuild QuickFIX/J with the updated message dictionnary (instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29971247/243373)). I don't know whether that will work though as `ResetSeqNumFlag` is a pretty basic field that is controlled by configuration. Still it's worth a try if your customer is unwilling/incapable to abide by the FIX standard specification.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try fiddle with the message in your `Application.fromAdmin` or `Application.toAdmin` overrides (ie, remove the `ResetSeqNumFlag` in the `Logon` message). That's easier to try out than my previous suggestion.

Comment: @TT. That's essentially what I ended  up doing. It's pretty hacky, but it works.